# How to allow page access ONLY by form in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, url

I have a page in wordpress that there is a form, which the user passes email and name. When the registration is completed, I will capture your data on a MailChimp, in my case, and redirect it to another page, which will have access to a simulation, for example.

However, I would like access to this redirected page to be made, ONLY, by my described form.

I do not want to be able to type in the url directly the address of the redirected page. Example: domain.com.br/simulado

If he did, he would enter the home again, or whatever. Anyway, how can this restriction be done?

Comment: You can set a `$_SESSION` variable when your form is submitted and then check for this variable before allowing access to the page.  http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: Sessions are not enabled by default in WordPress but this should help you https://www.ironistic.com/using-php-sessions-in-wordpress/

Comment: Thanks. Can i do this with the ContactForm7 plugin? Or any other you can tell me?

Comment: I'm not sure if ContactForm7 has hookable functions, if not you'd probably need to modify its PHP files, which would likely break when you update the plugin.

Comment: So, how can i do this? Do you know any plugin that allow me to do this? Or other way without plugin

Answer (score 1):

in the form add this:

```
<?php
$_SESSION['keyphrase'] = substr( md5(rand()), 0, 20)
?>
<input type="hidden" name="keyphrase" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['keyphrase"; ?>">
```

Then in your locked down page:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['keyphrase']) || !isset($_POST['keyphrase']) || $_POST['keyphrase'] != $_SESSION['keyphrase'])
{
    unset($_SESSION['keyphrase']);
    header("location: ".KICKBACK.URL);
    exit;
}
// UNSET IF YOU ONLY WANT TO ALLOW ACCESS ONCE
unset($_SESSION['keyphrase']);

// WELCOME
```

Answer (score 1):

**First** you need to enable PHP sessions on WordPress, add the following to your theme's `functions.php`

```
function start_session() {
    if(!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
}

add_action('init', 'start_session', 1);
```

**Next** you'll need to hook into Contact Form 7 and set a `$_SESSION` variable authorizing viewing of the redirect page, we'll use the hook `wpcf7_mail_sent`

```
function set_session_auth(){
    $_SESSION["auth"] = "authorized";
}
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', 'set_session_auth');
```

**Finally** on your redirected page we need to check for authorization.  The easiest way to do this would be to set up a custom PHP file for your page, ie `page-siumulado.php` which will contain:

```
if(isset($_SESSION["auth"]) && $_SESSION["auth"] == "authorized"){
    //Output your page content
} else {
    echo "Sorry you do not have authorization to view this page.";
    //or something to that effect.
}
```

**Keep in mind** this will set the `$_SESSION` variable any time Contact Form 7 sends a mail, so if you are using it for other forms they will also unlock the page.  You may need to set some conditionals.